# ironrouter onRun doesn't fire?

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, iron-router

I'm going off the IronRouter docs and using an onRun event, but I can't get it to fire. Is there something wrong with this usage?

I realize onRun isn't fired from a hotcode push, but even navigating away and returning to the same URL doesn't seem to fire it.

```
Router.map ->

  @route 'slots/tags',
    path: "/slots/:tags"
    data: ->
      console.log("IR:data")
      blob = {
        params: @params
        tags: @params.tags
      }
      window.blob = blob
      return blob

    # wtf it doesnt seem to run?
    onRun: ->
      console.log("IR:onRun")

    action: ->
      console.log("IR:action")
      createSlotsGame(@)
      @render 'slots'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not an issue,
try to add this (javascript native style) at the end of your onRun call:

`this.next();`

The documentation is lacking this. It only specify to add that call on following hooks : onBeforeAction, onAfterAction
But you need to call it on onRun and onReRun.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a bug with current IronRouter.
https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1219